# error: conversion from 'QStringList' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qlist, qvector

This is my class:

```
// file .h
#ifndef UNDOREDO_H
#define UNDOREDO_H

#include <QUndoCommand>

typedef QVector<QStringList> vector_t ;

class UndoRedo : public QUndoCommand
 {
 public:
     UndoRedo(QList<vector_t> v,
                    QUndoCommand *parent = 0);

     void undo();
 private:    
     QList<vector_t> *cb_values;
 };

#endif // UNDOREDO_H
```

```
// file .cpp
#include "undoredo.h"

UndoRedo::UndoRedo(QList<vector_t> v,
                   QUndoCommand *parent)
    : QUndoCommand(parent)
{
    cb_values = &v;
}

void UndoRedo::undo() {    
    QString last = cb_values[0][0].takeLast();
    qDebug() << last << "removed!";
}
```

When I call undo() method the IDE raises this error:

*error: conversion from 'QStringList' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested*

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor, you're taking the address of a parameter that will vanish when the constructor returns:

```
cb_values = &v;
```

This line will compile, but it's nonsensical. As soon as the constructor has returned, the pointer stored in `cb_values` is dangling and its further use may cause, well, your hard drive to be formatted.

Let's decompose `cb_values[0][0].takeLast()`.

```
QList<vector_t> * cb_values
QList<vector_t> cb_values[0]
QVector<QStringList>=vector_t cb_values[0][0]
QStringList cb_values[0][0].takeLast()
```

So, the type of your expression is `QStringList`, but you're trying to assign it to a `QString`. I don't know what you really wanted to achieve. Perhaps `(*cb_values)[0][0].takeLast()`?

Comment: Yes, is just (*cb_values)[0][0].takeLast()

Answer (score 1):

`cb_values` is pointer to `QList<vector_t>` so `cb_values[0]` is `QList<vector_t>`. So `cb_values[0]` is `vector_t`, or `QVector<QStringList>`. Then you call `takeLast()` on this vector, and it returns `QStringList`, which you try to assign to `QString`. Looks to me that you are calling `takeLast()` not on an object you wanted.